# I'm having problems with indentation in python coding, but I am not able to find the exact problem in order to fix it

Tags: python

`Unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<unknown>), line 47) pylint(syntax-error) [47,1]`

Code:

```
def takeCommand():
    #It takes mircrophone input from the user and return string output

    r = sr.Recognition()
    with sr.mircrophone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'eng-ben')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:                  (the problem is in this line)
        #print(e)
         print("Pardon me? Would be able to repeat that for me?")
         return "None"
    return query
```

to create a virtual assistant.

Comment: I think you need to write `except:` with colon.

Comment: What does the `f` in `print(f"User`... mean?

Comment: @dome: Look at the end of that line to find the colon.

Comment: The lines in the `except` catch have 9 spaces before them instead of what you want to be 8. Also this compiles fine in my python.

Comment: Is it that `#print(e)` is one letter to the left? Try adding 1 extra space so it lines up with print/return underneath.

Comment: @ScottHunter the `f` represents an [f-string in python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

Comment: When I run this code it works perfectly fine

Comment: The line in the `except Exceptiion` block needs to be one space closure to left.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the lines below the commented part in the below code. Can you move the lines below the comment(#) back by 1 space.

`except Exception as e:                  (the problem is in this line)
        #print(e) 
        <-print("Pardon me? Would be able to repeat that for me?") 
        <-return "None"`

Answer (score 0):

Running your code through pylint (after commenting out the "problem here" comment) I get the following:

```
$ pylint doit2.py 
************* Module doit2
doit2.py:12:50: C0326: No space allowed after keyword argument assignment
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'eng-ben')
                                                  ^ (bad-whitespace)
doit2.py:16:17: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
doit2.py:17:65: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
doit2.py:17:0: W0311: Bad indentation. Found 9 spaces, expected 8 (bad-indentation)
doit2.py:18:0: W0311: Bad indentation. Found 9 spaces, expected 8 (bad-indentation)
doit2.py:1:0: C0111: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
doit2.py:1:0: C0103: Function name "takeCommand" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
doit2.py:1:0: C0111: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
doit2.py:4:4: C0103: Variable name "r" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
doit2.py:4:8: E0602: Undefined variable 'sr' (undefined-variable)
doit2.py:5:9: E0602: Undefined variable 'sr' (undefined-variable)
doit2.py:15:11: W0703: Catching too general exception Exception (broad-except)
doit2.py:15:4: C0103: Variable name "e" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
doit2.py:15:4: W0612: Unused variable 'e' (unused-variable)

------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -5.71/10
```

I assume your question is about the `W0311: Bad indentation` comments generated by the python linter. Namely you need to delete one space before each of the `print` and `return` statements inside of your catch-exception block.

Another possibility is that you copied-and-pasted tabs from your python file (probably one on the `catch` line), which became spaces in your post. In which case [you should change any tabs in your python file to spaces as per PEP-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119576/1542000).

And while we're at it, the following modified version passes the lint-checker with flying colors:

```py
""" Takes a command """

def take_command(speech_rec):
    """
    It takes mircrophone input from the user and return string output
    """

    result = speech_rec.Recognition()
    with speech_rec.mircrophone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        result.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = result.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = result.recognize_google(audio, language='eng-ben')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except (speech_rec.UnknownValueError, speech_rec.RequestError):
        #print(e)
        print("Pardon me? Would be able to repeat that for me?")
        return "None"
    return query
```

In this code we've (1) deleted trailing whitespace at the end of the file (2) changed the 9 spaces to 8 spaces, (3) added docstrings for the module itself and the function, (4) changed variable names to more meaningful names and snakecase names, (5) caught more specific exceptions based on the library being called.